# Let $f=u+iv$ is an entire function. If $u+v$ is bounded then is $f$ constant or not? $(u=Ref(z)$ and $v=Imf(z))$

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-functions, entire-functions

$u+v$ is bounded $\Rightarrow$ $(u+v)^2=u^2+v^2+2uv$ is bounded $\Rightarrow$ $|f|^2+2uv$ is bounded.

What can I do further to reach the conclusion? or this is not the way to reach there?

Thank you.

Comment: Maybe try using Liouville's theorem? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_(complex_analysis)

Comment: @JacksonHsu: That was my first thought but we don't have $f$ bounded yet.

Comment: Do you know that if the real part of an entire function is bounded, the function is constant?

Comment: @EricWofsey Yep I know that if real part of $f$ is bounded then $f$ is also bounded. :)

Answer (score 3):

Hint: One approach is to use the fact that if the real part of an entire function is bounded, then the function is constant.  Can you construct from $f$ an entire function whose real part is $u+v$?

Comment: Interesting; this didn't occur to me. Perhaps you might want to give a little more hint on how to prove the fact. I suppose you first show that the real part must be a constant if it is bounded, and then the imaginary part must also be constant.

Comment: I constructed $g$ such that $g=(u+v)+iv$. Then $g$ and hence eventually $u+v$ and $v$ are constants using the given fact that $u+v$ is bounded. Then $u$ is also constant. Which asserts that $f$ is constant. :)

Comment: I hope I am correct.

Comment: @Eric Wofsey...Is it sufficient to show that $g(z)=U + iV$ is constant where $U=u+v$?

Comment: @VikrantDesai: It is not at all obvious that the $g$ you constructed is holomorphic.  Instead of constructing the real part and imaginary part of the function separately, try constructing a complex function which will obviously be holomorphic because $f$ is, and whose real part will be $u+v$.  Since $f$ has real part $u$, you just have to add to it a holomorphic function whose real part is $v$.

Comment: @mathlover: It's not obvious that it is, since that only gives you that $u+v$ is constant.

Comment: Is it right to use this arguement ? Since $u+v$ is bounded, then both $u$ and $v$ are necessarily bounded and hence using the fact that $\Re \: f$ bounded $\implies f$ is constant...

Comment: @Hirak: No, that's not correct.  You cannot deduce that $u$ and $v$ are bounded immediately from the fact that $u+v$ is bounded.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more ? Because even if one of them is unbounded then $u+v$ will not be bounded. What am I missing ??

Comment: Consider if $u=-v$, for instance.